# What is the cause of the blackening of leaves?

Tags: plant-health, indoors, plant-care, diseases

My plant leaf seems to have diseased. It's leaf seems blacken on edge and cut on middle. [image]

[image]

**Even new leaf is getting this problem.**

[image]

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.